# Nginx doesn't show php error even display_error is on

Tags: php, nginx

I have a website with nginx and php here my phpinfo

https://sundaysea.com/phpinfo.php

as you can see in phpinfo that display_error is on but in this page
https://sundaysea.com/clementcheng-com/

the page gets an 500 error and doesn't show any error. 
I tried to look into log files but there is nothing about this also

can you please help me to know where is the error?

I added this to my wp-config.php file also, it's a wordpress site

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // Disable display of errors and warnings define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
 @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

Comment: showing us your configuration file will help us help you

Comment: it could be a server/nginx error. can you check the error log file?

Comment: Check your web servers error log. Display errors can be disabled in the application. How to turn it on depends on the app. Does your application contain any `ini_set()`? Any `debug`-config?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, i don't think it does any ini_set it's just a wordpress website

Comment: Ah. That's an important part. WP does definitely set display_errors on and off depending on the configuration: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added this to wp-config but doesn't have nay difference

 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

Comment: Please edit your question and add the above code correctly formatted. It's not really readable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

when you restart nginx it doesn't restart php.
try

```
$ sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

it helped me. But you set your php version